# Numbers without remainder python

Tags: python, numbers, integer

I need to print out numbers between 1 and n(n is entered with keyboard) that do not divide by 2, 3 and 5. 
I need to use while or for loops and the remainder is gotten with %.
I'm new here and I just don't understand the usage of %?
I tried something like this:

```
import math

print("Hey. Enter a number.")

entered_number = int(input())

for i in range(1, entered_number):

    if i%2 != 0:
        print("The number", i, "is ok.")
    else:
        pass
    if i%3 != 0:
        print("The number", i, "is ok.")
    else:
        pass
    if i%5 != 0:
        print("The number", i, "is ok.")
```

help?

Comment: What's the problem? What output did you expect and what output you are getting? Anyway, one thing I can say for sure: all the `else:pass` could be omitted since they are *useless*. Also why are you doing `i%3` twice and I can't see any `i%5` around...

Comment: why not just use one if statement? using AND

Comment: Oh, damn, i missed i%5 out. That's the point, I need to print out all the numbers that do not divide by 2, 3 and 5 and I don't know how to do it. Sorry for being a new one, but I just started learning this and I want to understand. @Bakuriu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to test for all 3 conditions in **one** statement, not in 3:

```
for i in range(1, entered_number):    
    if i % 2 != 0 and i % 3 != 0 and i % 5 != 0:
        print("The number", i, "is ok.")
```

The `and` operators here make sure that *all three* conditions are met before printing.

You are testing each condition in isolation, which means that if the number is, say, 10, you are still printing `The number 10 is ok.` because it is not divisible by 3. For numbers that *are* okay, you were printing `The number ... is ok.` 3 times, as your code tests that it is not divisible by 3 different numbers separately, printing each time.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Moving forward now.

Comment: You can only mark *one* answer as accepted, I am afraid. I'm glad you found *all* answers to be helpful, but only one of us can be given the 15 points. Sorry!

Comment: sorry! didn't know this.

Comment: Not a problem! We were all new at this once. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If something divides by 7 then:

```
something % 7 == 0
```

If something divides by 7 *and* 9 then:

```
something % 7 == 0 and something % 9 == 0
```

Conversely, if something divides by 7 *or* 9 then:

```
something % 7 == 0 or something % 9 == 0
```

Something that does *not* divide by 7 *or* 9 is given by the expression:

```
not (something % 7 == 0 or something % 9 == 0)
```

You don't require the `else: pass` bits from your code and one if statement with an if-expression that has three `%, ==` bits in it should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check the three conditions at the same time:

```
if i%2 != 0 and i%3 != 0 and i%5 != 0:
    print("The number", i, "is ok.")
```

Otherwise, you would print the same message several times for a single number.

Anyway, for your second question, the`%` operation is called `modulo` and it gives you the remainder of a division. For instance, `5%3 = 2` because `5 = 3*1 + 2`. And when you check `i%2 != 0`, you actually check if i can be divided by 2.

Comment: He has a `else` in its original code, so I guessed that instead of the `pass` statement, he would have done something instead later on.

Comment: I just wanted to say that else is really not needed here. Thank you so much, I understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Hey. Enter a number.")
entered_number = int(input())
for i in range(1, entered_number):
    if i%2 != 0 and i%3 !=0 and i%5!=0:
        print("The number", i, "is ok.")
```

`a%b` returns the remainder when `a` is divided by `b`. Example:

```
>> 5%3
2
```

What you are doing wrong here is that you are printing after checking a single condition so it will print even if `i` is divisible by other numbers. For example if `i` is 3, it will satisfy the first condition and therefore print that the number is ok but it is actually divisible by 3.

Answer (score 0):

I saw you've solved your problem but my answer may worth reading.

This problem is actually doing filtering over a list of numbers `1..n`. You can define a base function to test if number `x` is dividable by number `y`, and then use this base function to filter the list to get the result.

Here's my version.

```
import math
from functools import partial

print("Hey. Enter a number.")

entered_number = int(input())

def not_dividable_by(x, y):
    return False if x % y == 0 else True

number_list = range(1, entered_number)

for i in [2, 3, 5]:
    test_func = partial(not_dividable_by, y=i)
    number_list = filter(test_func, number_list)

for number in number_list:
    print("%d is OK" % (number,))
```